# how to sum the field of two diferent table with different field using between date and group bydate in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
    public List<BillModel> Daily_Sales_Report(String from) {// passing the
```

date to getting the data, date wise from both the table
                    List list = new ArrayList();
                    String query="select sum(Discount),sum(Del_ch),sum(Pkg_ch),substr(Created_Date,0,11) from BILLING where substr(Created_Date,0,11) like '"+from+"' group by substr(Created_Date, 0, 11)";
                    String query1="select count(*),sum(Amount),sum(gst_price),Created_Date from cart where Created_Date like '"+from+"' group by Created_Date";

```
//here i used to cursor for getting the result from two different table and setting in the model class setter.
                Cursor cursor = this.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(query, null);
                Cursor cursor1= this.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(query1,null);
               if (cursor.moveToFirst()&& cursor1.moveToFirst()){// cursor and cursor1 will check the data from first positon 
                    String bill_date= cursor1.getString(3  ); //getting the date from table bill
                    String cart_date= cursor.getString(  3);//getting the cart_date from cart_table
                    try {
                        do {
                            if (bill_date==cart_date){ //if cart_date from cart_table ,and bill_date from bill_table will match then it will set in the setter other wise condition will check countiue in while loop                                   BillModel model = new BillModel(); //model class
                                 model.setbill_count( cursor1.getInt( 0 ) );   // here its for count total number of item
                                model.setC_Amount( cursor1.getFloat( 1 ) );
                                model.setB_total_gst( cursor1.getFloat( 2 ) );
                                model.setB_discount( cursor.getFloat( 0 ) );
                                model.setB_del_ch( cursor.getInt( 1 ) );
                                model.setB_pack_ch( cursor.getInt( 2 ) );
                                model.setB_create_date( cursor.getString( 3) );
                               list.add( model );
                            }
                       } while (cursor.moveToNext()&& cursor1.moveToNext());// using while loop for both the cursor
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e( "Error", String.valueOf( e ) );
                    } finally {
                        cursor.close();
                        cursor1.close();
                    }
                }
                return list;
            }

i am trying to this,What's I am doing wrong here,not getting the result in model class variable. Is it write way or not?
```

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify your problem.

Comment: In your case, table Billing_table have unique Index then don't sum billing rows.

Comment: actually i want to show data accoring to the date wise,  there it will show the number of data related to date will show like if date is 23/10/2019 between this date i can have multiple bills that's what i need,that's why i m sum the billing rows

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the way you are saving dates. According to SQLite, your "Created_Date" field is a string.

> SQLite compares strings letter by letter

**Example:**

According to SQLite 01/11/2019 is less than 21/10/2019 since the first date starts with '**0**' and the second date starts with '**2**'.

---

To fix this issue, you can use different date formats like

- **yyyy/MM/dd** : 2019/11/01
- **yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss** : 2019/11/01 14:21:43

Comment: hey i don't think this is the issue but it working many place i have used this format only in this case it's not working

Comment: @rachna for this case the dates are not the problem, but you **must** change their format. SQLite is not that flexible with dates. The only comparable format is `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: actually it 's 02/11/2019 ,my mistake but it's not working, do you know how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

The result you are getting is the correct response for the query you have written. The result is the effect of the left join.

> Example

The resulting table of a 'left join' without 'group by' would be

```
select * 
from CART left join BILLING on CART.index=BILLING.index 
where substr(BILLING.Created_Date,0,11) = '02/11/2019'
```

[image]

Here there are two rows in 'CART' with index=1 and there is only one row in 'BILLING' with index=1. So when 'left join' is used, the billing row will appear twice.
So when you use the 'group by' those values get added up.

Comment: actually i had used inner join before this but on that case also getting the same result

Comment: cart_id and index is two different filed index can be repeated but cart_id will not

Comment: if there are multiple cart-rows with the same index, then while using joins Billing-rows will be duplicated

Comment: what should i do for not getting duplicate value